# How to replace specific Symbols [like ' , ^ , \t' , etc..,] in a tsv file using linux commands?

Tags: linux, replace, symbols

I am trying to replace certain symbol combinations in a tsv file as below,

Occurance of ^' should be replaced as Nothing
Occurance of /t' should be replaced as /t
Occurance of ' should be replaced as Nothing

Finally,
I should replace the starting and ending " in any cell to nothing whereas " occuring in middle of any cell value should remain same. [Eg : "Apple iphone" should be replaced as Apple iphone and 7" Samsung LED TV should remain same]

**Sample File :**

7" Inch TV  "Apple Iphone"  \t' india \t'   ^' Exit all 'PAPS'

If you copy the above line into excel it will be into different columns.

**Code I tried :**

```
sed "s/\^'//g" ${file}.txt > ${file}_new.txt
sed "s//t'//t/g" ${file}_new.txt > ${file}_new_1.txt
```

Please, help me out of this friends.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what's the problem? why do you mix forward- and backslashes (e.g. `/t` vs `\t`)? how do you intend to delimit the columns (which are delimited by tabs), if you allow tabs within values?

Comment: my exact problem is i have downloaded a file, inside that file i am able to find /t instead of \t followed by a single quote which exactly looks like _[/t']_ on which i should perform a replace action and make it as _/t_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i still don't fully understand your problem, you probably want to:

- specify multiple filters with sed
- make sure that special characters (e.g. `/` which is often used to delimit the search-pattern and the replace-pattern) are properly escaped.

e.g. the following should do the trick:

```
sed -e "s|/t'|/t|g" \
    -e "s|[^]'||g" \
    -e "s|'||g" \
    -e 's|"\t"|\t|g' -e 's|^"||' -e 's|"$||' \
    "${file}.txt" > "${file}_fixed.txt"
```

This is using the pipe-character `|` instead of `/` to structure the search/replace command. It also uses 4 different replace-patterns directly.
Order is important: we start with the biggest-chunks to be replaced, and gradually make them smaller (so we replace `^'` before we replace `'`).
The last line is a simplistic way to get rid of the double-quotes (first removing the doublequote-tab-doubleqoute between columns; then removing any leading or trailing doublequotes)

Comment: Thanks for the timely help friend

Comment: Thanks for sharing the way how i should use stack overflow. I will follow going forth